In i18next, is it possible to use a different default locale for formatting - {{val, datetime}} - than for the overall locale?
I would like to respect the user's language preferences for formatting (for example, mm/dd/yyyy vs dd.mm.yyyy) even if I don't support their language and fall back to en.
Without i18next I can do this by passing the detected language, eg de-DE to the first parameter of the Intl.* APIs. I know I can do this on a one-by-one basis in i18next too, but is there a way to specify a default when initializing i18next?
note: I am using Next.js SSR, so I have the locale from the header but it is not the "default" one for the Intl APIs.

This was user-error. It does indeed work like this if you pass the user's locale to the lng property of init (with a fallbackLng of course).
